# Redirect non www. URL to URL with www

Tags: .htaccess

To let people access my website whether they type the www. in front or not where do I place the .htaccess file to do this as I have tried it and it won't work.

**I now know that I need to place the .htaccess on the non www. server and need to know how to access this to put it there.**

Comment: 1. You may want to set up DNS correctly to tell others that `www.xxx.yyy` maps to same address as `xxx.yyy` do. 2. You may want to setup `VirtualHost` of config file correctly (accept `www.xxx.yyy` as well as `xxx.yyy`), but I don't know how to do this exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place this file in the root of the folder. Make sure the file is called .htaccess and does not have an extension at the end ie .htaccess.txt.

If the directory in which your website is held for example is

```
/var/www/mysite
```

then this is the directory where the file needs to be placed. Depending on how your web server is set up, apache may not allow the use of htacess files. To overcome this do the following.

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
```

and open “default” up in your editor or choice, eg

```
sudo nano default
```

Default for AllowOverride is none, it should be All, so your overall “default” file                            should look like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *
ServerAdmin admin@site.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
```

If you do not have ssh access, you may need to speak to your webhost.

**Additional Comments**
If the htaccess file is confirmed as working then you need to add the following code to the htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This would forward all traffic to http://site.com

Or for the other way around

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Both of these will obviously need you to replace example.com with your site address. This is one way to do this, or you could add a ServerAlias in your apache vhost file for that particular site.

Comment: The .htaccess file is working because it is working for my custom error pages.

Comment: See additional comments

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand.

Comment: I have added additional comments to my post about what need to be put into your htaccess

Comment: That does not work but please read the comments on the other answer to understand the situation better.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with htaccess. You need to make sure that when someone types `www.example.com`, it goes to the exact same place as `example.com`. This is a DNS issue. Find your domain registrar and set that up.

Then on your server, allow for both in your vhost config. You should see something like this:

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
```

Comment: There is lots of info online including this site which have code to redirect the non www. version to the version with www.

Comment: No but I was wondering whether I have to have access to the non www. server to redirect from it.

Comment: @user2820258 Of course you'll need access to the non-www server to redirect from it. The request for `example.com` will go only to `example.com`, anything that has anyhting to do with `www.example.com` won't even be in the picture. This is why both need to be **on the same server**

Comment: That's what I thought and said in my original question.
So how do I access the non www. server.